# How to overcome negative integer outputs in infinite fibonacci series in c++?

Tags: c++, c++17, integer-overflow

I tried making infinite fibonacci series in c++ but after few terms it is showing negative integers. Here's the code:

```
int main(){
    long long int a{0};
    long long int b{1};
    long long int c{1};
    
    cout<<a<<endl<<b<<endl;
    
    while (true){
        cout<<c<<endl;
        a=b;
        b=c;
        c=a+b;
    }
}
```

I guess its because of size limit of long long int, but is there any way I can print upto infinity like in python?

Comment: No numerical type, or no type at all, for that matter, can print numbers "up to infinity", because that would require an infinite amount of storage. You should look into "BigNums", though, as I think that'll satisfy your needs for this program.

Comment: There is no standard type to store arbitrary precision numbers. You can find a third-party library or write your own. I think that for learning purposes writing your own limited-functionality library would be a very useful exercise.

Comment: @Telescope But I tried the same code on python and it was printing very very large numbers, almost upto infinity. why isn't there any storage issue in that case?

Comment: @sudhanshu Python is doing the same thing as the external library will do.  It is just hidden from you.

Comment: @n.'pronouns'm. I'm just a beginner so it would take time to mess with libraries. Thanks though :)

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Oh ok I get it now. Thanks :)

Comment: @sudhanshu If you only want positive number, you can use an `unsigned long long` to get twice the range.

Answer (score 1):

As others have mentioned, there is no standard type that has infinite precision.  You will need to use a third-party library, or write your own class that has this functionality.

One such library that implements arbitrary precision integers is [boost multiprecision](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_74_0/libs/multiprecision/doc/html/index.html).

Here is an implementation of computing the first 500 numbers:

```
#include <boost/multiprecision/cpp_int.hpp>
#include <iostream>

int main() 
{
    using Int = boost::multiprecision::cpp_int;
    Int a{0};
    Int b{1};
    Int c{1};
    
    std::cout << a << std::endl << b << std::endl;
    
    for (int i = 0; i < 500; ++i)
    {
        std::cout<< c << std::endl;
        a=b;
        b=c;
        c=a+b;
    }
}
```

[Live Example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1b7574087ce9f3b5)